# How to enlarge UDP buffer size in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, udp, buffer

I create an UDP socket using CFSocketCreate() for receiving data under iOS.
The UDP socket has 20% data loss.(80KB receive and 20KB loss in 5 minutes).

Then I googled and told me that I can enlarge the socket buffer size. (SO_RCVBUF by setsockopt() in linux)

But how can I do it under iOS, and how big the buffer size should I set to?

Thanks!

Comment: I summon a new thread for the socket handling. So it can't be block by  main UI thread.

Comment: Does the buffer clear when I reconnect the socket? Because I have a NSTimer and do reconnect socket every 10 seconds.

Comment: Additionaly, I use AsyncUdpSocket. ( CocoaAsyncSocket library )